# Ajax JavaScript variable to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to send a JavaScript dictionary variable to PHP using Ajax with JavaScript/jQuery `$.get` method, but it produces an error.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
$.get( "contr.php", { max: "max", max2: "max2" } );
```

And PHP:

```
$max = $_GET['max'];
var_dump($max);
```

- jQuery works
- JavaScript `$.get` works

The PHP error is:

> undefined index max

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to `var_dump($_GET)`.

Comment: Maybe address of file is wrong. Check that file address is right.

Comment: if address was wrong he wouldn't be getting undefined index error, he would be getting a 404..

Comment: are you using an mvc on the server? an .htaccess file?

Comment: $_get return the data i send from an other submit form but i dont get my max variable.
i tried with $.post and it return empty
Address is not wrong because i got the php error
im using on localhost without mvc framework

Comment: You shouldn't be quoting the variable name. But that won't cause an undefined index, it would cause `$max` to contain the literal string `"max"` instead of the variable value.

Comment: What happens if you go to the URL `contr.php?max=1&max2=2` in the browser?

Comment: Array $_GET is correctly dislayed if i go the url,
Okay, didn't know i followed example in openclassroom for $.get with quoted variable.

Answer (score 1):

The error is helpful. It says your dictionary variable passed to `$.get` has omitted the keyvalue pair `data` -> `max`. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "contr.php",
  method:"GET",
  data:{
        max: "max"
        max2: "max2"
       }
}).done(function(response){
    alert(response)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url : "contr.php",
    data: {
        max : "max",
        max2: "max2"
    },
    success : function(data){
        // Do some stuff
        console.log(data); // Use this to check the page response
    }
})
```

Refer to [this link](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) on the jQuery site :)

Comment: i tried this code also but it doesnt works.
`$.get( "contr.php", { max: "max", max2: "max2" } )` is a shortcut and logically leads to the same result

Answer (score -2):

Replace your Ajax code with this one:

```
    $.get( "contr.php", { "max": "max", "max2": "max2" }, function(res){} );
```

Comment: quotes on property names and the third parameter are optional.

Comment: in some browsers the name of property without quotes are consider as variable.

Comment: Not when in front of a `:` they are not

Comment: no, in all browsers the quotes on property names are optional. to use variables as object names square bracket syntax is required.